# Data refreshing issue in EF code first method

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Hi Im developing an WPF application using Entity Framework Code first method and Generic Repository pattern. My problem is at the time WPF application is running when I do a change to the data in the data base, WPF application data not showing that modified latest data. it is keeping all the data in the cache and not getting synch with the database. I have to close my application and need to rerun it to get the modified data. How can i resolve this problem. please help

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal RcerpDbContext Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public GenericRepository(RcerpDbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = Null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = includeProperties.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = DbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        DbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        var entry = Context.Entry(entityToUpdate);
        var primaryKey = DbSet.Create().GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entityToUpdate);

        if (entry.State != EntityState.Detached) return;
        var set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        var attachedEntity = set.Find(primaryKey);
        if (attachedEntity != null)
        {
            var attachedEntry = Context.Entry(attachedEntity);
            attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are satisfied with a refresh button or you need this reload to be automatic ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new DbContext once you know it is refreshed (or if you want to check if any data has changed).

Your repository should ask for a `Func<RcerpDbContext>` to be injected, so it can dispose of the current context, and create a new one using the `Func<>`, once it knows it needs reload collections of data from the database.

Otherwise if you only want to reload a single entity, you can use:

```
Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload()
```

Also if you do not want EF to keep a local copy you can use

```
Context.Set<TEntity>.AsNoTracking()
```

which will force EF not to store any local copies. Beware, that if you change your entity, and try to call `SaveChange()` **NOTHING** will happen. You will manually have to tell EF which propertied have been updated.

**EDIT 1**

If you want to reload a whole set:

```
Context.Set<Car>().Local.ToList().ForEach( x=>
{
  Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Although I would highly recommend either

1. Using a new Context and disposing of current one.
2. Using the AsNoTracking() modifier for your queries.

Comment: I think the point is that he does not know when the data has changed. The WPF app is running and data is simply changed directly in the database for instance. The app does not get a trigger for this.

Comment: Yes. the problem is I cannot track when the data get changed. is there any way to bypass the cached data and get data directly from the database.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck considering the statement "is there any way to bypass the cached data and get from database" it sounds like his problem is EF is giving him back the `Local` copy of the entities, so he cannot check if anything has changed.

Comment: a simple requery would suffice, with each requery you go to the db again. If you want to access local data you have to use the DbSet.Local. The point is that you don't need a new context at all. I still think the point is that the op does not know when the db has changed, so even a refresh button is then not enough, when is the user supposed to press the button ? Hence my question to the op at the beginning.

Comment: not every reqeury will go to Db, if you do a Find/Query with a filter on primary keys, EF will go to Local set first to see if it already has it.

Comment: that is correct, but a find i do not consider a requery. I really meant a requery on the DbSet directly and not via local. With the tiny bit of code of the op I still don't know what he wants to achieve.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Now Im trying to reload my entity. but when I use 'Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload()'  it gives me a error saying 'The entity type InternalDbSet`1 is not part of the model for the current context.'       what should  I enter for "T" and "entity". thanks :)

Comment: do you want to reload single entity or a whole set?

Comment: see edit for detaching all entities from a single set

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @MichalCiechan and. as you mentioned in the Edit 1, reloading the whole set worked like charm to me. :) . It solved my problem. I would also like to know is there any performance issue will occur when the data load get increased in the database in the future. Thank you.  :)

Comment: Yes, detaching entities one by one, is a fairly intensive process, you are better off disposing onf the context, and creating a new one, that will be cheaper. Also as to your finding differences, i would highly recommend introducing a LastModified timestamp column (and index). So you can go to the database, and get anything that has changed since the time you retrieved the data. This will save you retrieving the whole set each time just to find out if anything has changed. Ideally something like this would be a done via 2 way messaging rather than constant querying of database.